# Activeadmin save value from checkbox as boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to save value from my checkbox's form as boolean, but i have got an array

Chunk of my log `"important"=>[""]`

or if i checked it

`"important"=>["", "true"]`

my table

```
t.boolean :important, :default => false
```

my form

```
f.input :important, :as => :check_boxes, collection: [true]
```

How to fix it?

i think problem in my form's input

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use

```
f.input :important, as: :boolean
```

Instead.

**EDIT**

`as: check_boxes` is meant for collections (selecting many values from a collection).